# How do I check that every element in an array is greater than the one before it?

Tags: arrays, ruby, integer, comparison

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of strings, which are themselves numbers.  So something like

```
["1", "2", "3", "5"]
```

How do I check that the integer version of every element in the array (except the first) is greater than the one before it?  So for instance the function performed on the above would return true, but an array like

```
["1", "5", "4", "6"]
```

would return false (because "4" is not greater than "5".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An alternative way to phrase your predicate is: "For **all** **cons**ecutive pairs of numbers, is it true that the second is **greater than** the first"? This can be almost directly expressed in code:

```
ary.map(&:to_i).each_cons(2).all? {|first, second| second > first }
```

By the way: this property is called "strict monotonicity".

Comment: I prefer this because it's much more obvious what the code is doing.

Comment: It should also be much faster.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot what `each_cons` stand for.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Yeah, `each_cons`/`each_slice` aren't exactly obvious.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) to see if the `arr` is already sorted by numerical value:

```
arr = ["1", "2", "3", "5"]
arr.uniq.sort_by(&:to_i) == arr
#=> true
```

If the elements are not unique, then the array fails automatically. Since that means two elements are of the same value i.e. one is not greater than the other.

Comment: Sadly I cannot guarantee that the elements will be unique, only that they will all be numbers (disguised as strings).

Comment: @Natalia If they're in order of lowest to highest, which they must be to meet your definition of "greater than the one before it", then it's sorted, ergo sorting should have no effect.

Comment: You can do it in O(n), though.